# How do I compare all cells in a datagridviewrow with multiple values and do something with the row that meets the condition of the comparison?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have 6 values which I want to compare with the cells of all rows in a datagridview.
The first value should be compared to the cell value of the first column, the second value to the second column, and so on. If there is a row where all 6 values match, the text in this row should be changed to green.

I have done some code but I don't know how to finish it.

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1e.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["CustomerName"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowName)
                && row.Cells["CustomerAddress"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowAddress)
                && row.Cells["ZipCode"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowZipCode)
                && row.Cells["City"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowCity)
                && row.Cells["PhoneNr"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowPhoneNr)
                && row.Cells["CustomerEmail"].Value.ToString().Equals(rowCustomerEmail))
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Simply set `row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text color try this:

```
row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```